# MegaRAID SAS Phy is bad on enclosure, no SAS address

Tags: hardware-raid, sas, megaraid, drive-failure

I've inherited a MegaRAID SAS 24 bay RAID, that is also attached to two additional enclosures ( one 24 bay, and one 12 bay).

I attempted to load 6 new drives into 6 consecutive empty drive bays on the 12 bay enclosure (bays 6 - 11) and all 6 showed a solid red error light, and the admin mailing list got 6 messages...

```
Controller ID:  0   Phy is bad on enclosure:   2  PHY
      11
Event ID:185
Generated On: Tue Feb 12 17:02:27 CET 2019

System Details---
IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.10
OS Name: Linux
OS Version:3.13
Driver Name: megaraid_sas
Driver Version: 06.700.06.00-rc1

Image Details---
BIOS Version : 5.37.00_4.12.05.00_0x05180000 Firmware Package Version: 23.9.0-0015 Firmware Version : 3.220.05-1881
```

Looking up the event ID in the documentation gives me:

```
Enclosure %s phy %d bad

Logged when the status indicates a device presence, but there is no corresponding SAS address is associated with the device.
```

- I put the 6 new drives in one of the other enclosures, and they worked fine (so not bad drives).
- There are 6 drives operating fine in bays 0-5.

It seems odd that all 6 sequential drive bays 6-11 should be bad, but apparently NOT the entire backplane is bad.

**Is it possible for only half of the enclosure's backplane to have gone bad? Or is this a firmware (or some other configuration) problem?**